# error with git (-bash: git: command not found)

Tags: git, console, rubygems

I am having trouble with `git` command. I'm getting `-bash: git: command not found`.
It's reported as installed when I run `$ gem list`, and i've put its path on my `.profile` as you can see below. I just don't understand how come it doesn't work. Thanks for the help

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-10-11_at_19:01:44: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# git path

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: I've change $PATH by ${PATH} and it still doesn't work

Comment: are you sure git is installed in _/usr/local/git/bin_ ? And you don't  just need /usr/local/bin in PATH? did you reload your .profile after modifying it (_source ~/.profile_)?

Comment: how do I get Git installed in the first place? My gems dont show any git installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [git](http://rubygems.org/gems/git) you have installed is a Ruby Gem that is used to access Git features from within Ruby. It does not come with the actual Git and as such does not include the command line `git` (I’m actually not sure if the Gem does not even *need* a normal Git installed).

So what you need to do is to download and install [Git itself](http://git-scm.com/download).

Answer (score 0):

On Mac:
The best solution is to install Xcode and then go to Xcode - Preferences, and the Downloads.
Here install Commandline Tools and you are good to go.